# expected string or bytes-like object al intentar buscar los números en un archivo .txt usando la librería re de Python

Tags: python

Quiero extraer todos los números en un archivo `.txt`; al importar la librería re en python y ejecutar el comando `re.search`, no logro que me funcione. Obtengo este error:

> expected string or bytes-like object

```
import re 
archivo = open('archivo.txt')

y = re.search('[0-9]',archivo)
print(y)
```

Comment: Necesitas leer el archivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Solución*

```
import re

patron = re.compile("(\d+)")
with open('test.txt') as archivo:
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        valores = patron.findall(linea)
        if valores:
            for valor in valores:
                print(valor)
```

Con expresiones regulares tienes cuatro formas de hacer la búsqueda:

- re.match. Revisa si el patrón calza al comienzo del string.
- re.search. Busca el patrón en todo el string.
- re.findall. Busca **todas** las ocurrencias; retorna una lista.
- re.finditer. Busca **todas** las ocurrencias; retorna un iterador.

Lo que necesitas es un `findall/finditer`, pues esos te devolveran todos los valores, sin importar donde se encuentren (dentro del string).

Cuando vas a repetir la búsqueda, conviene *compilar* el patrón primero para hacerlo más rápido:

```
patron = re.compile("(\d+)")
```

Este patrón reconoce una secuencia de 1 o más digitos `\d+`, y al ponerlo entre paréntesis `(\d+)`, *captura* el texto encontrado y te lo devuelve.

El archivo, por otra parte, hay que leerlo línea por línea y aplicar el patrón a cada una. Para eso se ocupa:

```
for linea in archivo.readlines():
```

Dentro del `for` vamos revisando línea por línea:

```
valores = patron.findall(linea)
```

Esto retorna una lista de valores, o `None` si no se encontró ninguno.

Si encontro valores, recorre la lista imprimiendolos:

```
if valores:
    for valor in valores:
        print(valor)
```

#### Demo

*test.txt*

```
Archivo de prueba
Los anos son 1999, 2000, 2001 y 2005
Los valores son 14, 154 y 82
1 2 3 4
Ultima linea
```

produce:

```
1999
2000
2001
2005
14
154
82
1
2
3
4

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: muchas gracias fue de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu variable es la información relacionada con el archivo y no con el contenido. Usando la función `type` puedes obtener el tipo de objeto que es

```
type(archivo)  # <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
```

Como puedes ver es de tipo [TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) y si miramos la documentación vemos que este objeto tiene un método que es [read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read) y es el que nos permite leer el contenido del dicho archivo.

Sabiendo esto, con una pequeña modificación tu código quedaría así.

```
import re 
archivo = open('archivo.txt')

y = re.search('[0-9]',archivo.read()) # Llamar al método para leer el contenido 
print(y)
```

Comment: Sería bueno hacer un *pre-procesamiento* del texto antes, así quitamos *texto basura*

Comment: Por supuesto, pero el OP ha dejado muy claro cual es el problema. Si tiene otro error/mejora siempre puede abrir otra pregunta.